# Spring framework и порты

Tags: spring

коллеги! У меня такой вопрос сделал тестовое приложение на Spring Boot, запускаю дебаг, чтобы проверить работает ли приложение, но в ошибке выдаёт, что 8080 порт занят, закрываю скайп (обычно из-за него он занят), все равно выдаёт ошибку. Уже скачал CurrPorts(утилита, которая позволяет убить порт), но даже это программа выдала ошибку, что якобы либо нельзя порт закрыть либо просто тупо не позволяет. Так вот в чем вопрос: Что мне сделать, чтобы приложение запустилось? Как мне порт поменять в проекте и тд? Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в чём соль, выбираем вкладку выше в панели Run -> Edit Configurations... -> в вкладке Configuration -> VM options -> -Dserver.port=8090 //меняем порт на 8090

Answer (score 0):

В `application.properties`:

```
server.port = 8090
```